# No boot messages are being diaplyed while booting FREERTOS

Tags: freertos

I asked a question on LCD display with FreeRTOS [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87730/how-to-display-characters-on-lcd-with-freertos/87777?noredirect=1#87777). This time my question is a little bit different so I am posting as a new question.

Normally I have seen that when we port Linux on any board having ARM, boot messages come automatically on the LCD. I saw this while porting Android/Angstrom on beagleboard xm.

But in my case when I ported FreeRTOS on the [EFM32 Giant Gecko board](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/32-bit-microcontroller-tools.aspx/efm32-giant-gecko-starter-kit-efm32gg-stk3700), nothing appears on the LCD.  I then ran a sample application given in simplicity studio that runs on FreeRTOS and blinks LEDs. This is the only way I know that RTOS is running.

I am expecting that boot messages should come on the LCD as in case of Beagleboard. How do I enable this feature. I guess LCD driver is disabled by default. I think I should try to enable it. Right?

The second approach is I use the [following function](http://cdn.energymicro.com/dl/documentation/doxygen/kits/common/bspdoc/html/group__SegmentLcd.html#ga40ac47768020f1b4e87463b0d91194d4) in the FreeRTOS code to print various messages. In a separate application I have used this function to print characters on the LCD successfully.

Is this the right approach to  display boot messages on LCD?

```
void SegmentLCD_Write   ( char *string   )      
Write text on LCD display.
    Parameters:
        string  Text string to show on display
            Definition at line 767 of file segmentlcd.c.
            References CHAR_TypeDef::bit, CHAR_TypeDef::com, 
            EFM_Alphabet,   SegmentLCD_AlphaNumberOff(), and MCU_DISPLAY::Text.    
Referenced by SegmentLCD_LowerHex(), and SegmentLCD_LowerNumber().
```

Answer (score 5):

You are assuming that every operating system "interacts" with a human. That is not true, and FreeRTOS is designed for applications where the operating system typically does not have a means for interaction or a need to do so. Therefore, FreeRTOS does not attempt to print or display any messages to a human observer.

FreeRTOS and Linux are vastly different, and they should be because they are intended for vastly different purposes. Your question is like complaining that the air conditioning on your bicycle doesn't work like it does in your minivan.

Comment: I got your point but still I am curios to know how to send boot messages to the LCD. Could you please add some specific details to your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

Displaying a message after booting is application-specific, so it's reasonable and expected for it to be part of the application code, as opposed to the RTOS or BSP. Why should an RTOS print boot messages when most embedded systems don't have a display?

Comment: I understand boot message display should be a part of O.S. If it is not then how anybody will interact? Also I have seen while booting Linux on PC, the boot messages come while  the O.S is still booting. Also Android on Beagleboard shows boot sequence and messages while it is still booting, and not AFTER booting is over.

Comment: @gpuguy Not to put too fine a point on it, but your understanding is simply incorrect.